# Return custom map as return type in a class

Tags: apex, lightning, map

I am trying to have a class with map as return type. I am not sure how to return a custom map.
Here is my code:

```
public static Map<String,Integer,Integer,Integer> getMdus() {
   Map<String,Integer,Integer,Integer> mdus = new Map<String,Integer,Integer,Integer>();
   mdus.put('bldg',activeUnits.size(),neverUnits.size(),coldUnits.size());
   return mdus;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This syntax is incorrect, but you have an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). We need to know what you're trying to do so we can help you. Please [edit] your question to describe what you're doing.

Comment: I am trying to pass a string with a few integer values to the helper file. In the above each row will have a string and few a integer values that is associated with that string.

Comment: You will have to create a Wrapper class since a map can only contain one value for the corresponding key. The 3 integer values should be part of a single object (the wrapper class).

Comment: @Aayush could you provide me with an example

Comment: Added example as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Aayush, will try it out tomorrow and update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper object to encapsulate multiple values within a single object.

Define a wrapper class.

```
public class UnitSizeWrapper{
    public Integer activeUnitSize {get; set;}
    public Integer neverUnitSize {get; set;}
    public Integer coldUnitSize {get; set;}
}
```

Use the wrapper class in your method.

```
public static Map<String,UnitSizeWrapper> getMdus() {
   Map<String,UnitSizeWrapper> mdus = new Map<String,UnitSizeWrapper>();

   UnitSizeWrapper wrapper = new UnitSizeWrapper();
   wrapper.activeUnitSize = activeUnits.size();
   wrapper.neverUnitSize = neverUnits.size();
   wrapper.coldUnitSize = coldUnits.size();

   mdus.put('bldg', wrapper);
   return mdus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except that you are using the map syntax incorrect. Please take a look at this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm